# WYSIWYG HTML JavaScript-based editor? (to replace TinyMCE)

Tags: text-editor, wysiwyg

I'm looking for a WYSIWYG editor that will let a user type and format text (bold, italics, insert links, etc) which I can then grab via jQuery as raw HTML code and do something with it. I've tried TinyMCE, but frankly it's terrible. It doesn't work as the documentation indicates, and the documentation is quite poor.

Fire away with any suggestions, please! Open source only.

Comment: Dear whoever removed the answer that I came back just now to look at: you are a cruel, cruel person.

Comment: Why was it removed? I'm only seeing one answer that's greyed out. I get downvoting an answer you don't like, but leaving no comments about it is worse than useless.

Answer (score -1):

Redactor, in my opinion, is the best and most user friendly HTML editor.
You should definitely check the list on sitepoint :
http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-wysiwyg/